# Triangles to make two different backgrounds in html and css

Tags: html, css, background, positioning

I am trying to create something like this image[image]

I tried to create two different triangles with two divs and managed to smashed them together to get achieve this but don't know how to put the text in them to make it look like this image. I am not even sure if the approach is right or not. Any improvements will be appreciated.

```css
#top {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 300px solid tomato;
  border-right: 600px solid transparent;
  display: inline;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}

#bottom {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 300px solid skyblue ;
  border-left: 600px solid transparent;
  display: inline;
  display: table-cell;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top">
  
</div>
  <div id="bottom">
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you looking for a responsive solution, or the elements have a fixed size?

Comment: A responsive solution is the one I'm after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sprazer/hk9761u9/
Very basic, not responsive yet

**EDIT** Responsive: https://jsfiddle.net/Sprazer/hk9761u9/

```
h2 span{
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
h2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 5  ;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sprazer, can  you please explain the code a little bit and was my approach to create split background was right or  is  there something a better alternative?

Comment: I've changed the fiddle, to be responsive now. The split background is a perfectly OK approach. I guess you could have a sharp linear gradient background, but that wouldn't work in older browsers.

The text  is just vertically aligned and separated so that each word take 50% of the width.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Cheers

Comment: Just thought should accept that one as an answer as well.

Comment: Hehe ok, there can only be one though ;)

Comment: Fairly new to so that's why it happend. I'm gonna change it now. Thanks